# Mutual syncronization of x folders

Tags: sync, rsync, unison, grsync

I am looking for a solution as to how I can synchronize an undefined amount of folders on my server. At the moment I have 3 folders, but it may increase in the future. Any of the folders can have files added to them and deleted, which should then be updated in the other folders. I imagine the synchronization should happen more or less instantly or at the very least every minute. After a file has been created in one folder, it may be queried in another folder soon after.

I have looked at rsync and unison, but haven't quite found a solution that works as I want it to. I may be wrong and rsync or unison may be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both rsync and Unison (among *many* other tools) will accomplish what you want. The difference between those two is that rsync is more minimal, like a beefed up `cp` or `scp`, and you will have to write some clever scripts and/or cron jobs to get the setup you want, while Unison takes care of more things itself. See the [Unison tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/unison/info) for more info.

Also, check out [all the other sync utilities available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software) too.